# Need some fixing SurfaceArea and LateralArea

Tags: c++

Hi guys I need some help fixing a basic [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) program. I'm getting errors on my `SurfaceArea`, and my `LateralArea`. The errors are below....

> called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
>
> invalid operands to binary expression('double' and 'double')

My code is below....

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; //allows me to use cout and cin w/o typing std in the main

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double height;      //initialzing my variables
    double bottombase;
    double topbase;
    
    double volume;
    double LateralArea;
    double SurfaceArea;
    

    cout << "Please type in the height: ";          //asking users for information in order to find volume, and surface area
    cin >> height;
    
    cout << "Please type in the length of one side of the bottom base: ";
    cin >> bottombase;
    
    cout << "Please type in the length of one side of the top base: ";
    cin >> topbase;
    
    volume = height * bottombase * topbase;
    
    cout << "Your volume is: " << volume << endl;
    
    LateralArea = 2(bottombase + topbase) * sqrt(((bottombase-topbase)/2)^2 + height^2);
    
    SurfaceArea = LateralArea1 + bottombase^2 + topbase^2;
    
    cout << "Your surface area is: " << SurfaceArea << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `2(bottombase + topbase)` should be `2 * (bottombase + topbase)`. also `^` is bitwise exclusive or. Use `pow` instead or just mutiply the number by itself

Answer (score 3):

You can't omit the multiplication operator, so `2(bottombase + topbase)` is wrong, needs to be `2 * (bottombase + topbase)`. Also the `^` operator does not do what you think it does. In C++ it's a bitwise XOR, most likely not what you had in mind. There is no power operator in C++, so if you have to take the square of something, say `x`, you should either do explicitly `x * x` or use the `pow` function as such: `pow(x, 2)`. You'll need to `#include <cmath>` to use `pow`.